# How to pull csv import into an associative array and name the keys automatically?

Tags: php, csv, associative-array, csv-import

I have a csv file where the first line shows the name of each row. This name should be the key for an associative array. Currently I am pulling this in manually and if the row order changes it will break the functionality.

How can I retrieve the names from line 1 and create keys out of it?

```
$csv = array();
$index = 0;
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    if ($row[0] == NULL) 
        continue;
    else{
        $index++;
        foreach($row as $csvdata){
            list(
                $csv[$index]['column 1 name'],
                $csv[$index]['column 2 name']
            )
            = explode(';',$csvdata);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to show us what the first few lines of your CSV looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the very first line of the file, which contains the names/keys, into an array.  Then use those keys to populate the associate array as you parse the remaining lines.

```
$keys = array();
$csv = array();
$index = 0;
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    if ($index == 0) {
        $keys = explode(',', $row);
    }
    else {
        $csv[$keys[index-1]] = $row;
    }
    ++$index;
}
```

This answer assumes that what you want here is an associate array where the keys correspond to the names in the first row, and the values correspond to each row in the CSV import.